# Remove Second Clear Button in Kendo-grid Row Filter

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

Starting with Kendo-UI 2017, I've noticed that the row filter now shows two "x" buttons to clear the filter (one inside the text box and one to the right of the text box).  Why are there two rather than only one like in the older versions?  More importantly, 
is there a setting to remove the clear button from inside the text box without resorting to using CSS?

[image: two "clear" buttons]

```js
$("#grid").kendoGrid({
    columns: [
        {
            field: "name",
            filterable: {
                cell: {
                    showOperators: false,
                    operator: "contains"
                }
            }
        },
        { field: "age", filterable: false }],
    filterable: { mode: "row" },
    dataSource: [{ name: "Jane", age: 30 }, { name: "John", age: 33 }]
});
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<link href="//kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.1.118/styles/kendo.common.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="//kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.1.118/styles/kendo.bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="//kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.1.118/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>

<div id="grid"></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The AutoComplete widget for filtering is to blame.  I ended up using CSS anyway to hide it:

```
.k-clear-value {
    display: none !important;
}
```

But the JavaScript answer was to put the following in the [dataBound event](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid#events-dataBound):

```
this.element.find(".k-filtercell .k-autocomplete .k-clear-value").remove();
```

Here is the updated code:

```js
$("#grid").kendoGrid({
    columns: [
        {
            field: "name",
            filterable: {
                cell: {
                    showOperators: false,
                    operator: "contains"
                }
            }
        },
        { field: "age", filterable: false }],
    filterable: { mode: "row" },
    dataBound: function(e) {
        this.element.find(".k-filtercell .k-autocomplete .k-clear-value").remove();
    },
    dataSource: [{ name: "Jane", age: 30 }, { name: "John", age: 33 }]
});
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<link href="//kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.1.118/styles/kendo.common.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="//kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.1.118/styles/kendo.bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="//kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.1.118/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>

<div id="grid"></div>
```

[Source](http://www.telerik.com/forums/remove-second-clear-button-in-kendo-grid-row-filter#hGjoTYQSZEepnmv8vacGlg)